# How to match all lines with common pattern in splunk regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to extract a report of all incidents matching a certain pattern and then need to plot how many occurances of each type. For example the below lines.

```
File: ../../../transfer/200.FILETYPE1.0000003115.20160419-082708-089.xml successfully imported.
some other logs....
File: ../../../transfer/200.FILETYPE1.0000003116.20160419-082708-090.xml successfully imported.
some other logs...
File: ../../../transfer/201.FILETYPE2.0000003117.20160419-082708-091.xml successfully imported.
```

**Please note that there are many filetypes but the pattern is same "/transfer/" prefix and "successfully imported." suffix and these prefix and suffix must match as other lines may also contain same file name before completion.**

So in above case I need to find all such occurrences of above lines and find count of each FILETYPE1 and FILETYPE2 in splunk.

Can someone help me with regex that can match above pattern and give me all such lines so that I can extract counts of each file type?

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward:

```
^File:.*FILETYPE\d.*$
# ^ beginning of the line
# File: literally
# .* anything to the end of the line
# FILETYPE + a number literally
# .* anything afterwards
# $ the end of the line
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lT6pL4/1).
***Hint***: If you only have these two strings (`FILETYPE1` and `FILETYPE2`) you might be faster with string functions only.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `FILETYPE1`/`FILETYPE2` for counting

```
\.\.\/.*\/\d+\.FILETYPE1\..*?\.xml
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH2yE0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\/transfer\/.*FILETYPE(\d+).*successfully imported
```

The file type number will be captured by the capture group, so you can count the file occurrences

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP4hW7/2)